# Is tensorflow_transform a going concern for tf 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-transform

For example, will it eventually work? Does it work? What are the goals and plans? Where can we read about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is tensorflow_transform a going concern for tf 2.0?

Absolutely! Development is ongoing. Issues are being actively discussed, PRs are being worked on and there have been several changes to the master branch this week.

> will it eventually work? Does it work?

Yes it works now (in general at least). Perhaps if you are encountering some specific issue could ask a new question with what, specifically, isnt working for you.

> What are the goals and plans? Where can we read about it.

The tensorflow team are really good at communicating plans via RFCs and doing development in the open. I am less familiar with work on tf-transform but all the signs are this is developed with the same culture. Check out:

- [the github repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/transform)
- [the official site](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/transform/install)